# complex numbers - Proving

Tags: complex-numbers, proof-writing

Prove algebraically that $|w+z|\le|w|+|z|$ for any complex numbers w and z.

This is what I got so far:
Since $|z|^2 = z \overline{z}$, we square both sides: $ |w+z|^2 = (w+z) \overline{(w+z)} \le (|w| + |z|)^2$. Since $\overline{w+z} = \overline{w} + \overline{z}$ we get

$|w+z|^2$

$ = (w+z) (\overline{w} + \overline{z})$

$ = w \overline{w} + z \overline{w} + w \overline{z} + z \overline{w}$

$ = |w|^2 + z \overline{w} + w \overline{z} + |z|^2 \le (|w| + |z|)^2$

Now what? I do not know how to proceed. Thanks!

Comment: Take square roots.

Comment: But what about the left hand side?

Comment: What about it? Taking square roots gives you $|w + z| \le |w| + |z|$.

Comment: @T.Bongers:  the $\leq$ signs are what he wants to prove, not what has been shown.

Comment: Yah...so what then do I do?

Comment: http://www.cut-the-knot.org/arithmetic/algebra/ComplexNumberInequalities.shtml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have assumed what you want to prove in the places you use $\leq$
Now you need $z\overline w + w \overline z \le 2|w||z|$, which will justify the last $\leq$ and allow you to take the square root of the chain.

Comment: I found that $ z^2\overline{w}^2 + w^2\overline{z}^2 \le 2 |w| |z|$ after squaring both sides and simplifying. How should I proceed?

Comment: If you have that, your last chain collapses to $|w+z|^2=|w|^2 + z \overline{w} + w \overline{z} + |z|^2 \le (|w| + |z|)^2 \leq |w|^2 + 2|w||z|+|z|^2=(|w|+|z|)^2$  The first equal is in your post, the $\leq$ is what you just said, the third is the binomial theorem.  As both sides of the inequality are positive, you can take the square root and be there

Comment: Squaring the required inequality:
$$(z\bar w+w\bar z)^2\ =\ z^2\bar w^2+w^2\bar z^2+2|w|^2|z|^2 \ \overset{?}\le\ 4|w|^2|z|^2$$
Which reduces to $(z\bar w-w\bar z)^2\le 0$ which holds because $s:=z\bar w-w\bar z$ is purely imaginary ($\bar s=-s$).

Answer (score 1):

It is anyway good to know that the expression
$\ z\bar w+\bar zw\ $ is just 2 times the *scalar product* of vectors $z,w$, in that, if $z=a+bi$ and $w=c+di$ then
$$z\bar w+\bar zw=2(ac+bd)$$
Then the inequality $z\bar w+\bar zw\le 2|z|\,|w|$ is just the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality: $\langle z,w\rangle \le |z|\,|w|$.